# Flutter Isolate.kill() with NATIVE allocate

Tags: flutter, ffi, dart-isolates

I create an isolate by `Isolate.spawn()` in my statefulWidget.

After the widget disposes of, will the isolate be **auto-cleaned** by GC?
Or is it necessary to manually kill the isolate?

If manual-cleaning is needed, is `isolate.kill()` enough?
What about `receivePort.close()` ?
Which operation is enough, `isolate.kill()` or `receivePort.close()`?
Or either is it enough ? Or both are needed?

If both are needed, which operation first, which second?
Does the order matters ？

In the spawned isolate, I allocated some **NATIVE** structs and arrays.
When isolate shuts down, will these native structs and arrays be **auto-freed**?
Or is it necessary to manually free these native pointers?

If manual-freeing is needed, is it safe to free these pointers in [onDone] function registered in `receivePort.listen()` ?
And, is it safe to call `isolate.kill(priority: Isolate.immediate)`?
Will pointers' freeing be ensured with `Isolate.immediate`?
Or should I choose `Isolate.beforeNextEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the implementation of [`compute`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart) function. I can safely say you need to manually exit the isolate. Wheter using [`isolate.kill()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate/kill.html) or [`Isolate.exit()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate/exit.html)